# How to get the value for a variable key from a pig map?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a way we can get the value of a map for variable keys using the field as the key?
Eg : My company data has locale and name fields like this

```
 {"en_US", (["en_US" : "English Name"], ["fr_FR" : "French Name"])}
```

What I want essentially is to get the value of the map using locale as the key as it will be different for different locales.

```
company_data = load '/data' using PigStorage();

final_company_data = FOREACH company_data GENERATE
                                             value.locale as locale
                                             value.name#locale;
```

The following gives me an error coz I understand that to retrieve a value from the map we need value.name#'en_US'. Is there a way we can use the locale so it gets substituted for the right value?

```
Output : final_company_data = {"en_US", "English Name"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember you can't do that in Pig. The key has to be static value. So eg this should work:

```
final_company_data = FOREACH company_data GENERATE
                                         value.locale as locale
                                         value.name#'en_US';
```

If the key set size is not too big you can try something like this (but this includes a lot of typing):

```
en = FILTER company_data BY value.locale == 'en_US';
final_company_data_en = FOREACH company_data GENERATE
                                         value.locale as locale
                                         value.name#'en_US';
fr = FILTER company_data BY value.locale == 'fr_FR';
final_company_data_en = FOREACH company_data GENERATE
                                         value.locale as locale
                                         value.name#'fr_FR';
```

and do this for every key and then do the union of all subsets. This solution is poor and ugly but it works.

Comment: Thanks for this example.

Comment: If this solves your issue you can upvote or accept the answer :)

Comment: It does.. I am just waiting to see if someone has something better coz I cant think of any alternative too.

Comment: You can always try to write an UDF.